# Alternative way to serve a react webpage

Tags: reactjs

So now I need to use `serve -s build` to serve a webpage created by  react. However, due to some limitations I do not want to install serve on my laptop. Thus, is there an alternative way to serve the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use basic file server with node.js 
https://gist.github.com/jonlabelle/9689998
or setup nginx as static server https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed